# Google Maps: Different color heat map based off of value

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, heatmap

I am currently working on an application that requires a heatmap. Based off of values in the data I would like to alter the gradient for that specific location. I have not found anything that has pointed me in the right direction. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

You can set the gradient.

```
heatmap.set('gradient', [ /* gradient */ ])
```